# XML NodeList is not empty but its node is null

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

So I have this XML File:

[image: XML File]

And what I am trying to do is to gain access to the children from "planView" using this code:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fileName);
NodeList myList = document.getElementsByTagName("planView");     

for (int i = 0; i < myList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nNode = myList.item(i);
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    System.out.println("idx is " + i +" and node is "  + nNode + " and elem is " + eElement);
}
```

And this is the output (from System.out.println):

```
idx is 0 and node is [planView: null] and elem is [planView: null]
```

Why is the node from the planview null?

Comment: planView has nothing in this xml but it has two children so if you want to access geometry node u need to pass "geometry" in getElementsByTagName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child nodes of `planView` needs to be accessed via method `getChildNodes()`:

```
NodeList planViews = document.getElementsByTagName("planView");

for (int i = 0; i < planViews.getLength(); i++) {
  Node planView = planViews.item(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < planView.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
    Node n = planView.getChildNodes().item(j);
    if (n instanceof Element) {
      Element e = (Element) n;
      System.out.println("s: " + e.getAttribute("s"));
    }
  }
}
```

It prints something like:

```
s: 0.000e+00
s: 1.000e+01
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.w3c.dom.*` classes are very unhelpful. You cannot just make + on them to a String and hope to obtain something useful.

It will only give you any kind of meaningful information if you call the correct methods, in the correct order, in excruciating details.

Maybe try using a thirdparty library, like JDOM 2. It adds to the dependencies of your project, but it's much more comfortable to use.